# Java Generics using specialized constructors

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an interesting problem that I have not found a good solution though Google.

I have the follow class signature

```
public class CCheckBoxList<T extends CGenericController<K>, K extends CGenericDomain> extends CGenericViewer<T, K>
```

For the class CGenericDomain (interface), the specialized classes have their own methods and a specialized constructor. The interface only has a getData and setData method for getting/setting data. The only way around an earlier problem I was experiencing.

In one of my implementations, I will have to set data using CGenericController (no problems) by passing in the object that is implemented using CGenericDomain (Ahhh!!!)

CGenericController and CGenericDomain use JPA so the controller reads/writes/modifies objects in a database while CGenericDomain are the objects that should be written in the database. Each main table has its own CGnericDomain implementation an dCGenericController implementation.

When instantiated this class, **I will know** what T and K are for. I explicitly define them during the building process of my program.

This is what I have figured out so far

```
public void setData(HashMap<String, Object> pObjs) {
    // TODO Add the required logic for adding into the list all values that are "selected" from an external function

    Class<K> clazz = null;
    try {
        K newK = clazz.newInstance();
        if (newK instanceof CGenre)
        {
            // Requires knowledge of the implementation further up stream!
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    itsContentPane.removeAll();
    itsContentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(pObjs.size() + 3, 0));
}
```

The options that I have come up with or uncovered in the Google searches are

1. Implement an instanceof method for all the objects that inherit CGenericDomain
2. Create specialized classes for all objects that would use CGenericDomain (you get a class, you get a class, everyone gets a class!)
3. Look into Abstract Factories and learn how to do that (how do I do that???)

Is there a reflective way to getting the specialized constructor of the class and using that? If not, how about methods? I might be able to do methods.

Any help from the community would be awesome. Venturing into new territory!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to nitpick straight away, but `K newK = clazz.newInstance();` will give you a NullPointerException as things stand. Where does `clazz` really come from?

Comment: If you actually need the specific classes at runtime, you should pass in `Class<K>` and `Class<V>` into the constructor of `CCheckBoxList` and store them as member variables.

Comment: To answer your question, I copied that from some code somewhere on the interest hoping that I would be able to gain something...sadly it didn't. I can setup the Class<K> and Class<V> but what will that gain me when done? Will I still need to use the if (newK instanceof CGenre) implementation?

Comment: It gains you a concrete instance of `Class<K>` (etc) on which you can call `clazz.newInstance()`. You can't call `K.newInstance()`. "Will I still need to use the if (newK instanceof CGenre) implementation?" Don't really know what you're trying to do. I tend to avoid instanceof calls because there are often other ways of doing it.

Comment: I will play around with passing in Class<K> as a parameter into the class constructor.
The code "if (newK instanceof CGenre)" that is to determine which object I am currently interfacing with. I agree that there are better ways than instanceof.